# Html upload control in mvc with multiple uploads without refreshing page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

when I uploading using html upload control in MVC the page refreshing because of return view("Index"). But I don't need any return type I am storing the data in Sessions.

How to call a Method from View without refreshing page for this specific requirement.

here is my view code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadAction", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "frmID" }))
{         
    @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.FilesToBeUploaded)
    <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" style="float: left; visibility:hidden;" />      

}

<script>
    $('#fileToUpload').change(function(){
        alert('submit');
        $("#frmID").submit()               
    });
</script>
```

My controller Code :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadAction(FileUploadModel model, List<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload)
{
    return view("Index"); }
```

Comment: Why not just redirect to another view?

Comment: @stephen I have to redirect the same view because my requirement like that, If you have any suggestion please share with me.

Comment: Then why not post using ajax (which stays on the same page).